# My database system cannot find the file specified in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data from a database with the following code:

```
public partial class populate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = populate");  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {     
        StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder(); 

        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                scmd.Connection = scon;
                scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM populate";

                scon.Open();

                SqlDataReader articleReader = scmd.ExecuteReader();

                htmlString.Append("'Populate page:'");                

                if (articleReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (articleReader.Read())
                    {
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["dateTime"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["firstName"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["lastName"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["address"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["details"]);                       
                    }
                    populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
                    articleReader.Close();
                    articleReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's throwing an error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

I am wondering if someone can show me where the error is or guide me through debugging this. Thanks in advance.

(update): More specifically, the scon.Open() is causing the error:

Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This looks easy enough to fix, but I'm not very good with the database. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the database has the same name with your table, populate? It's seems to me a bit odd.

Comment: @Christos: I know it's odd but it is the same: populate.mdf and the table is also called 'populate'.

Comment: **Where** (on which line of code) does it throw that error?

Comment: @marc_s: It looks like scon.Open(): Here's part of the error; Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: So that probably means your connection string is wrong - wrong SQL Server instance name most likely ....

Comment: @marc_s: Is it easy to fix, like can you see what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what SQL Server edition you have installed, and what you called it (as an instance name) .....

Go to `Start > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > Configuration Manager`; under `SQL Server Services`, search for the `SQL Server` service - what is it's name??

[image]

If it's `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`, then that means you have the Express edition, with an instance name of `SQLEXPRESS` - change your connection string to:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=populate;Integrated Security=true;
```

If it's `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` then you *should be fine* really - you have an unnamed, default instance ....

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am using sqlexpress. I tried the new string with 'Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS' but it's the same error at 'scon.Open()'. This link below gives a lot of flexibility to the connection string ((local), localhotst):https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx or is it not really.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: After studying and testing Management Studio for a little while I came to understand when my attached .mdf database was active. Until then I assumed that if the MS was running then my db was active; incorrect. Everything's working now, just needed connecting to MS..