# “The system cannot find the specified file” error when trying to display data from database to datagrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, datagrid

I'm trying to display data on `datagrid` from database but getting this error.

> “The system cannot find the specified file”

```
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
namespace AdoNetExample  
{  
public partial class DataGridExample : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=student; integrated security=SSPI"))  
        {  
            SqlDataAdapter sde = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from student", con);  
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
            sde.Fill(ds);   //SHOWING ERROR AS IT IS HIGHLIGHTED IN RED
            DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;  
            DataGrid1.DataBind();  
        }  
    }  
}  
}
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Which type of error you are getting @Thor. Kindly show us

Comment: It says system cannot find the specified file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My database system cannot find the file specified in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354807/my-database-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing your data source.

```
new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=student; integrated security=SSPI")
                               ^ 
                              here
```

Please give [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) a read